# Java Recursion - Capture Parent Category based on Child Property

Tags: java, recursion

```
Class Category
{
  private String id;
  List<Category> subCategory;
  List<Products> products
}
```

Is there a way to get all the categories which has products or any of its subcategories has products.

```
package algorithms;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Sample {

// The below recursion is capturing only last child nodes not the parent.   

private static boolean recursion(Catalog currentCatList, List<Catalog> extractedCatsList) {
    if(currentCatList.getSubCat() == null) {
        return currentCatList.getProducts() != null;
    }
    Iterator<Catalog> subCatItr = currentCatList.getSubCat().iterator();
    while(subCatItr.hasNext()) {
        Catalog cat = subCatItr.next();
        boolean hasProducts = recursion(cat, extractedCatsList);
        if(hasProducts){                
            extractedCatsList.add(cat);
        }           
    }
    return currentCatList.getProducts() != null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Catalog cat = new Catalog();
    cat.setId("catId_1");
    createSubCategories(cat,1);     
    List<Catalog> extractedCatsList = new ArrayList<Catalog>();
    recursion(cat,extractedCatsList);
    System.out.println("extractedCatsList >>>>> "+extractedCatsList);
}

// Below 2 only to create sample request -

public static void createSubCategories(Catalog cat,int SubCategoriesNeeded){    
    List<Catalog> subCat = new ArrayList<Catalog>(2);
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= SubCategoriesNeeded; i ++){
        Catalog subCat1 = new Catalog();    
        subCat1.setId("subCat_"+i);
        createSubSubCategories(subCat1,2,i);            
        subCat.add(subCat1);        
    }
    cat.setSubCat(subCat);
}

public static void createSubSubCategories(Catalog cat,int SubCategoriesNeeded,int subCatIndex){ 
    List<Catalog> subCat = new ArrayList<Catalog>(2);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < SubCategoriesNeeded; i ++){
        Catalog subCat1 = new Catalog();    
        subCat1.setId("subCat_"+subCatIndex+"_"+i);
        if(subCatIndex != 1 && i%2 == 0){
            List<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
            products.add("prodSubSub"+i);
            subCat1.setProducts(products);
        }
        subCat.add(subCat1);        
    }
    cat.setSubCat(subCat);
}

}
```

I tried the above with recursion method and got all the last Subcategories but not sure how to identify the parent categories whose subcategories has products.

Expected Output - 
catId_1, SubCat_0, SubCat_0_0.

But the above is giving only SubCat_0_0. It should give the expected as above.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
private ArrayList<Category> found = new ArrayList<>();

private boolean searchInside(Category category) {
  boolean hasProduct = false;
  boolean subCategoryhasProduct = false;
  if ((category.products != null) && (category.products.size() > 0)) {
    found.add(category);
    hasProduct = true;
  }

  if (category.subCategory != null) {
    Iterator<Category> subCategoryIterator = category.subCategory.iterator();
    while(subCategoryIterator.hasNext()) {
        Category subCategory = subCategoryIterator.next();
        if (searchInside(subCategory)) {
            subCategoryhasProduct = true;
        }

        if (!hasProduct && subCategoryhasProduct) {
          found.add(category);
        }
    }
  }

  return hasProduct || subCategoryhasProduct;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ariel, But  I see it is capturing - SubCat_0, SubCat_0_0 for the above , not the root catId_1.

Comment: @Suraj already fixed. The issue was that i was modifying the `subCategoryhasProduct ` on each iteration, but it just need to set `TRUE` if there is at least one subcategory with products. Also maybe you should improve the code avoiding duplicates in the `found` array